# Typescript extract generic arguments from generic class type

Tags: typescript

I have class such as:

```js
class Foo<T> {
    // ...
}
```

My use-case is, that `T` is always a certain type that itself has two generic type parameters, such as:

```js
type Bar = BarBase<'number', number>;
```

Now, I want to pass `Bar` to `Foo` and extract `Bar`'s generic type params:

```
Foo<Bar> // I want to access the types 'number' and number

type Bar2 = BarBase<'string', string>;
Foo<Bar> // I want to access the types 'string' and string
```

Is this at all possible? I would have guessed `infer` (e.g. `class Foo<T<infer A, infer B>>`) but this does not work.

Note for all you C++ folks out there: What I am looking for is a TypeScript variant of template template (yes, it is actually 2x template) parameters.

Comment: You can't say `T` is a type with two type parameters. You can describe the shape of `T`. You can say `T extends  BarBase<any, any>` and then use conditional types to extract the types from the instantiation of `BarBase` (using conditional types). But `T` could be any type that is a subtype of `BarBase<any, any>` not necessarily a direct instantiation of it

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/wgXYBN) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: You may be asking for *higher kinded types* as in [ms/TS#1213](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213), which are not directly supported.  Or you may just want to write `class Foo<X, Y> { ... }` and instead of using `T` you use `BarBase<X, Y>` everywhere.  Or maybe something else; it's hard to tell because I don't know what `BarBase` is, and I don't see enough use cases (is it sometimes `BarBase<X, Y>` and sometimes `BazBase<X, Y>`?  Or is it always `BarBase<X, Y>`?  Is `T` always *equal to* `BarBase<X, Y>` or does it just *extend* `BarBase<X, Y>`? Etc. A complete example would help.